# Connected components of algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be an algebraic group, and $G_{Id}$ the connected component of the identity. Then $G_{Id}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/G_{Id}$ is the component group of $G$.

Let $G_{c}\subset G$ be another connected component of $G$. Is is possible to define a group structure on $G_c$?

Assume we know that for any connected component $G_c$ of $G$ we have an injective morphism $f_c:G_c\rightarrow H\times F$ where $H$ is a group and $F$ a finite group. Now, for any $g\in g$ there exists a unique connected component $G_c$ such that $g\in G_c$ and we may define a map 
$$f:G\rightarrow H\times F,\: g\mapsto f_c(g).$$
If $f$ is surjective can we conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: The answer to your first question is certainly yes, since there is a bijection between the set $G_c$ and the connected component of the identity (which is usually denoted $G^\circ$ or the like).   The answer to the second question is presumably no, but the formulation is not quite clear to me.

Comment: If the base field isn't separably closed, it's possible that a non-identity connected component might not have a rational point, in which case it can't possibly be given the structure of a group scheme over the base field. For example, $\mu_3=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Q}[X]/(X^3-1))$ has two components, both single points, and the non-identity one is not a $\mathbf{Q}$-rational point (and incidentally splits into two components over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3)$). But maybe you want your base field to be algebraically closed?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming the base field to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each connected component is (in a natural way) a torsor under the identity component. The choice of a rational point (if there is one) defines an isomorphism with the identity component, and makes the component into an algebraic group.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for the answer. I will rephrase my second question in a more precise way.

Answer (score 4):

To expand my short comments, it's possible (though not usually interesting) to place a group structure on any component $G_c$ using an obvious bijection between this set and the connected component of the identity.

Concerning the second question, look at a maximal torus $T$ in a connected simple algebraic group such as $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.   Usually the normalizer $N:=N_G(T)$ isn't a direct product of a finite group and $T$ even though you could write each connected component as $\{n\} \times T$ for an element $n$ of the finite (hence algebraic) Weyl group $N/T$.   This sort of thing happens for example in special linear groups, where the Weyl group is a symmetric group.